# Zyxel modem - killed ping to router on other pc startup

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

When I use my computer (A) and someone else in the network starts up computer B, three times internet doesn't work for 5 seconds. Using cmd I figured out that the router wasn't pingable at the bios screen, login screen and at the start of the desktop of Windows of computer B. After that, internet works again properly. How can I solve this issue?

Router:
[Zyxel p-2812hnu-f1](http://www.zyxel.com/nl/nl/products_services/p_2812hnu_fx_series.shtml?t=p)

ISP: Telfort NL.

Computer A + B: Windows 7, laptops.

Comment: This is... strange. Does the router have any sort of logging in the admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I contacted my ISP again they told me that it is a common problem with the Zyxel P-2812HNU-F1. In a month we will get a new fiberglass connection and a better modem plus a router. Then this problem will be solved, they promised.